# Python Firestore Event Listener Stopped Working after adding a new variable to be checked

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, eventtrigger

The idea behind this script is to listen to new users that sign up to my web app, for their signing process I have added a variable called "newUser" leaving it by default in True. I check if that user is new (in the "If newUser == 'True', I am saying that True is a string since a line before I am using the get() and to_dict() methods to extract the "True" which I think comes out as a string).
Then the script continues, finds the new user's First Name and the new user's Phone Number and send them to be converted to json and send to a webhook.
Until yesterday my script and webhook were working fin, this before I am checking for this new variable called "newUser", by the end of the script I change the variable "newUser" to False.

BTW: My firestore collection is called 'users', each user's document has an autogenerated ID, and the comes the subcollection where I have two maps that I am interested in, one is "info" which contains the user's personal details, as FirstName and Phone Number, and the other is this main, where newUser is and is set to True (by default).

I am not sure if the logic of the script is correct, I checked my webhook and its listening without problem, the firestore trigger is running with no error, but it seems that the webhook is not being triggered.

Anyone has any idea?

```
#Required Libraries
import time
import json 
import requests 
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore, credentials, threading

#Connection Details
cred = credentials.Certificate("bondupProd.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
print("Connection Established Successfully!")

#Access to Firestore
db = firestore.client()
print("Connection to Firestore DB Succesfully!")

#Create an event for notifying main thread
callback_done = threading.Event()

#Create function to check if newUser is True
def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if (change.type.name == 'ADDED') or (change.type.name == 'MODIFIED'):

            new_user = db.collection(u'users').document(
                change.document.id).get(
                    {u'main.newUser'}).to_dict()['main']['newUser']

            if new_user == 'True':

                firstName=db.collection(u'users').document(
                    change.document.id).get(
                        {u'info.firstName'}).to_dict()['info']['firstName']

                userPhone=db.collection(u'users').document(
                    change.document.id).get(
                        {u'info.phone'}).to_dict()['info']['phone']

                print(firstName, userPhone)

                msgBird="https://flows.messagebird.com/flows/...." (webhook)

                data = { "firstName": firstName,"userPhone": userPhone }

                requests.post(msgBird,data=json.dumps(data),headers={"MessageBird-Signature-JWT":"sl9zzUwEAVgJlu0qhDIP8gzu0iKy9amR", "Content-Type":"application/json"})

                #Update newUser to False
                db.collection(u'users').document(u'{usersId}').update({'newUser': False})


# Watch the collection query
col_query = db.collection(u'users').where(u'main', u'array_contains', u'newUser')
query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Script running!")
```

Solutions? Something to change?

Comment: the question is too convoluted, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

> I am saying that True is a string since a line before I am using the
> get() and to_dict() methods to extract the "True" which I think comes
> out as a string

Your mistake may be here.

The boolean values in Firestore (like in every JSON) are still booleans in Python, not strings. It is true for any method you use to retrieve the value: a `doc_snapshot.to_dict()["key"]` will provide the same type as a `doc_snapshot.get("key")`.

This means that when you write `.update({'newUser': False})`, the field will really be equal to `False` and not `"False"`. If for some reason you want a string, write `.update({'newUser': "False"})`.

We can't see the code where the document is created with field `'newUser'` set to `True`, but it is very likely that it is a boolean, so you have to change your check  to

```
if new_user == True:
```